# div with morethan one horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Hello I have declared a div `<div id="variantTable" style="overflow-x: scroll;width: 750px;">` 
 and it appears like the following
[image: the scrollbar is shown twice]

I tested this on chrome, firefox and IE8 and the problem only appears on the latter, unfortunately this is the desired browser to work on. could anyone help with that?

Comment: Check the parent container and set maybe `overflow: hidden` also check if your `<div>` tags are closed properly `</div>`

Comment: I'm sure the second scrollbar does not belong to the `div` you mean, it may belong to another element, just find that element and your problem will be solved.

Comment: no it is not written twice I checked that in the freemarker file and on the created html and when I remove the div, both scroll bars disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It causing because you are using `overflow-x: scroll;` two times in parent or child div or in a page.

I just made a Demo to reflect the same issue you are facing. Check ***[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/lugiwoqo/1/)***.